# How can I delete all files in my folder, except Music -subfolder?

Tags: shell, terminal

#### Duplicate

> [Unable to remove everything else in a folder except FileA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635378/unable-to-remove-everything-else-in-a-folder-except-filea)

I guess that it is slightly similar to this:
delete [^Music]

However, it does not work.

Comment: You already asked this question (and Adam gave the accepted answer). Why post it again?

Comment: @Can: I did not post it again. I edited my old question to up to date. I can't remove it.

Comment: @Masi: yeah, I just noticed. Actually, the other question is the duplicate. Either way, I think one should be closed.

Comment: @Please, close this question as no longer relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the following command to your ~/.bashrc

```
shopt -s extglob
```

You can now delete everything else in the folder except the Music folder by

```
rm -r !(Music)
```

Please, be careful with the command.
It is powerful, but dangerous too.

I recommend to test it always with the command

```
echo rm -r !(Music)
```

Comment: he asked about fish shell, this is a bash option. does it also work in config.fish?

Comment: @bjeanes: Fish shell is buggy, so I changed the question. I considered Bash in answering the question.

Comment: "rm -r !(Music)" works in gnome-terminal but does not work in .sh file. It say "syntax error near unexpected token `('"

Comment: if you want to use this command in .sh file you can use it like this:
shopt -s extglob
rm -r !(client-deployment-webapp)
it works for me. Thank you.

Comment: @SaeedZarinfam Note that in your script you need either a semicolon or a line break between `extglob` and `rm`.

Answer (score 2):

The command

```
rm (ls | grep -v '^Music$')
```

should work.  If some of your "files" are also subdirectories, then you want to recursively delete them, too:

```
rm -r (ls | grep -v '^Music$')
```

**Warning**: `rm -r` can be dangerous and you could accidentally delete a lot of files.  If you would like to confirm what you will be deleting, try looking at the output of

```
ls | grep -v '^Music$'
```

*Explanation*:

- The `ls` command lists directory contents; without an argument, it defaults to the current directory.
- The pipe symbol `|` redirects output to another command; when the output of `ls` is redirected in this way, it prints filenames one-per-line, rather than in a column format as you would see if you type `ls` at an interactive terminal.
- The `grep` command matches lines for patterns; the `-v` switch means to print lines that *don't* match the pattern.
- The pattern `^Music$` means to match a line starting and ending with Music -- that is, only the string Music; the effect of the `^` (beginning of line) and `$` (end of line) characters can also be achieved with the `-x` switch, as in `grep -vx Music`.
- The syntax `command (subcommand)` is fish's way of taking the output of one command and passing it over as command-line arguments to another.
- The `rm` command removes files.  By default, it does not remove directories, but the `-r` ("recursive") option changes that.

You can learn about these commands and more by typing `man command`, where `command` is what you want to learn about.

Comment: "rm -r (ls | grep -v '^Music$')" works in gnome-terminal but does not work in .sh file. It say "syntax error near unexpected token `('"

Comment: add `rm -r $(ls | grep -v '^Music$')` @SaeedZarinfam

Answer (score 0):

So I was looking all over for a way to remove all files in a directory except for some directories, and files, I wanted to keep around. After much searching I devised a way to do it using find.

```
find -E . -regex './(dir1|dir2|dir3)' -and -type d -prune -o -print -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

Essentially it uses regex to select the directories to exclude from the results then removes the remaining files. Just wanted to put it out here in case someone else needed it.