# Shell - Remove everything except a single folder

Tags: bash, shell

I have a directory containing one single folder named `.git` along side various other files and folders. I want to delete all files and all folders, except for my `.git` directory.

Note that if any of the folders contain a subfolder named `.git`, I want to remove those as well. Only the root git repo should be preserved!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is that simple as :

```
shopt -s extglob dotglob
rm -rf !(.git)
```

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob

Comment: Thanks! I was trying [a similar script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/453581/how-can-i-delete-all-files-in-my-folder-except-music-subfolder#comment16380887_647981) which wasn't working. I thought it was the period in the name interfering with pattern matching, when it really was a missing line break.

Comment: I think you need `shopt -s dotglob`. Otherwise, you might as well just use `rm -rf *`.